# Reading/Parsing a .ddd (digital tachograph - second generation) file in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, json, xml-parsing

I need some way to read/parse .ddd files (tachograph second generation - new smart ddd) in NodeJS. I found solutions like jugglingcats https://github.com/jugglingcats/tachograph-reader , but when I tried reading new smart card ddd its was quite insufficient.

Comment: Any progress on the issue?